# How to make a list with variable number of items in Ionic React?

Tags: reactjs, list, ionic-framework

I want to create a list with a variable number of items in Ionic React. Up to now, I'm aware of this approach. The items of my list are stored in the *examples* array:

```
          <IonList>
            {examples.map((example) => (
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel>{example}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
            ))}
          </IonList>
```

The items of this list are seperated by a line below each item. Unfortunatelly, a line is also displayed below the last item. My idea to prevent that is to exclude the last *example* from the code block above and treat it seperately:

```
              <IonItem lines="none">
                <IonLabel>{lastExample}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
```

In this case I would need to wrap a condition around this block to prevent the  and  to be rendered if there are no examples and both, the *examples* array and the *lastExample* variable, are empty.
How can I implement this condition in the code? Is there a better practice of making a list with the last item looking different than the items before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @sharun k k, I found a solution. In your post was still an error because the conditional expression returned type `'false | "none"'`, but `false` is not allowed. It has to be `undefined` instead. I modified the solution slightly using the `?` conditional operator:

```
    {examples.map((example, index) => (
      <IonItem button lines={examples.length - 1 === index ? "none" : undefined}>
        <IonIcon icon={personCircleOutline} slot="start" size="large" />
        <IonLabel>{example}</IonLabel>
      </IonItem>
    ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use condition inside your map to get the last element.
use `index` to get the element no

```
<IonList>
            {examples.map((example,index) => (
              <IonItem lines={examples.length-1 === index && "none"}>
                <IonLabel>{example}</IonLabel>
              </IonItem>
            ))}
          </IonList>
```

when last element is returning lines will become `"none"`

Comment: There is still an error:
  Type 'false | "none"' is not assignable to type '"none" | "full" | "inset" | undefined'.
    Type 'false' is not assignable to type '"none" | "full" | "inset" | undefined'.ts(2322)